# How can I remove this? ...(process 4652) exited with code 0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

So.. I am noob, and I just created a c++ empty project in Visual Studio 2017.

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

This is all I have in 'main.cpp', and 'main.cpp' is the only thing I've added/done in this project.

I started without debugging and it results :

```
E:"location_of_the_file" (process 1276) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I have no idea how to remove that first line.
Please help!

Comment: Why do you need to remove that line?

Comment: To remove the line, you can debug with a different debugger or use different IDE.

Comment: hmm... I was following a lecture, that line wasn't there. It seems others don't have that either. I thought something went wrong. Do you think it's not a big issue:P?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should be visible only when you run the application in Visual Studio.

There is no reason to disable this line, it only allows you to see return result when debugging. When you run the application outside of Visual Studio, this line will not display.

I see this:

> MyApp.exe (process 9076) exited with code 0.
>
> To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
>
> Press any key to close this window . . .

There you can see how to disable this when you need to disable it.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was overreacting. <:"D

Comment: Don't worry. I was also surprised when I saw this behaviour for the first time. Maybe because I saw the full length message, I did non overreact at least.

Answer (score -1):

I did not like this long text either. Instead of return 0; in the main function. I suggest that you replace it with system("pause>0");

This way, you will only see the output :)